# Sql to get all the friends of friends who's not my friend

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a "Possible Friends" feature. where i need to show all the friends of friends who's not my friend and also not send me or not having my pending request

```
FRIENDSHIPS
user_id
friend_id
status  (0 = pending, 1 = approved)
```

For each friendship I make two records. Say users 1 and 2 become friends... I would make a record `where user_id=1,friend_id=2` and another `where user_id=2, friend_id=1` in the `friendships` table.

when first user send request, set status to 0 and when friend accept request then I would update both row with 1

How would I make a sql query that suggests "possible friends" based on friends of my friends ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go... simple join

```
SELECT F2.friend_id
FROM FRIENDSHIPS F
JOIN FRIENDSHIPS F2 ON F.friend_id = F2.user_id
WHERE F2.friend_id NOT IN (SELECT friend_ID FROM FRIENDSHIPS WHERE user_id = @user_id)
  AND F.user_id = @user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

<s>I think you could also use a sub-query (?) to retrieve the same information.</s>

SELECT friend_id 
    FROM FRIENDSHIPS
    WHERE user_id IN
    (SELECT friend_ID FROM FRIENDSHIPS WHERE user_id=@YOURUSER_ID AND status=1)
    AND friend_id<>@YOURUSER_ID

```
SELECT friend_id 
FROM FRIENDSHIPS
WHERE user_id IN
(SELECT friend_ID FROM FRIENDSHIPS WHERE user_id=@YOURUSER_ID AND status=1)
AND friend_id NOT IN
(SELECT friend_ID FROM FRIENDSHIPS WHERE user_id=@YOURUSER_ID AND status=1)
AND friend_id<>@YOURUSER_ID
```

I think will work but the join method is much simpler.

Comment: I disagree. Its two queries.  The first brings back a list of all the approved friends of YOURUSER_ID.  The second select brings back all friend_ids where the user_id is in the list produced by the first query, unless the friend_id is equal to YOURUSER_ID.

Comment: Yes you are right, the first list all your friends the 2nd lists all their friends, but it does not exclude your friends just cases where you are listed as their friend.  For example, if I'm a friend of A and B and B is a friend of A this query would list A.

Comment: Yes this works, using a link improves performance for the first sub-query but not the second because a smart optimizer will just run the second query once.  (A really smart optimize would perform the join optimization for you and only perform the first once too.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-)

```
select * from FRIENDSHIPS pf 
JOIN FRIENDSHIPS f ON pf.friend_id=f.user_id AND pf.status=1 AND f.status=1   
JOIN FRIENDSHIPS me ON me.user_id = f.friend_id AND me.user_id = MY_USER_ID AND me.status=1 AND f.status=1 
WHERE me.user_id <> pf.friend_id AND me.friend_id <> pf.user_id
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this :)

```
SELECT  f2.friend_id<br>
FROM    FRIENDSHIPS f1<br>
JOIN    FRIENDSHIPS f2<br>
ON  f1.friend_id=f2.user_id<br>
WHERE   f2.friend_id NOT IN (select friend_id from FRIENDSHIPS where user_id=@user_id)<br> 
    AND f1.user_id=@user_id <br>
    AND f2.friend_id!=@user_id<br>
```

Comment: Note the answer with 3 upvotes and the green check to the left of it? This means, that this answer has already solved the problem.

Comment: @fancyPants - also this answer is wrong.  The final where clause is not needed.