# How to find friends of friends who are not my friends in two way relationship in SQL

Tags: mysql

My data set:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL COLLATE `utf8mb4_bin`,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE=`utf8mb4_bin`
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

CREATE TABLE `friends` (
    `friend_one` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `friend_two` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `status` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `requested_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE INDEX `friend_one_friend_two` (`friend_one`, `friend_two`),
    INDEX `IDX_FRIEND_ONE` (`status`, `friend_one`, `friend_two`),
    INDEX `IDX_FRIEND_TWO` (`status`, `friend_two`, `friend_one`),
    CONSTRAINT `FK_FRIEND_ONE` FOREIGN KEY (`friend_one`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `FK_FRIEND_TWO` FOREIGN KEY (`friend_two`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE=`utf8mb4_bin`
ENGINE=InnoDB
;

INSERT INTO users(id, username) VALUES
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(3, 'C');

INSERT INTO friends(friend_one, friend_two, status, requested_id) VALUES 
(1, 2, 1, 1),
(1, 3, 1, 1);
```

SQLfiddle of same: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10dba9/5

I would like to fetch friends of friends from my friends table.

I enforce friend_one is always smaller than friend_two (1 < 2)
and always assume 1 -> 2 friend relationship is 2 -> 1 using status key (0 being pending, 1 being friends)

Now I wish to get friends of friends:
1 -> 2 and 1 -> 3 are friends and I wish to recommend 2 to 3 or 3 to 2 saying 
"You have a mutual friend 1!"

This is how I get friends

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, f.friend_one, f.friend_two, f.status, f.requested_id
  FROM users u 
  JOIN friends f 
    ON f.status = 1 AND f.friend_one = 1 AND f.friend_two = u.id
 UNION ALL
SELECT u.id, u.username, f.friend_one, f.friend_two, f.status, f.requested_id
  FROM users u 
  JOIN friends f 
    ON f.status = 1 AND f.friend_two = 1 AND f.friend_one = u.id
```

### UPDATE 1

I referred to this but it looks like the table does not enforce `id 1 < id 2`
[Finding mutual friend in one way relationship table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17690616/finding-mutual-friend-in-one-way-relationship-table)

### UPDATE 2

I think I found a solution in here 
[Sql to get all the friends of friends who's not my friend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819654/sql-to-get-all-the-friends-of-friends-whos-not-my-friend)

I do not know whether this one inner join will affect the performance. Is there a way to use join in this case?

```
SELECT u.id, u.user_id, u.username, F2.friend_two, F2.status
  FROM friends F 
  JOIN friends F2 
    ON F.friend_two = F2.friend_one 
  JOIN users u 
    ON u.id = F2.friend_two
 WHERE F2.friend_two NOT IN (SELECT friend_two 
                               FROM friends
                              WHERE friend_one = 2) 
   AND F.friend_one = 2 
   AND F2.`status` < 1 
    OR NULL
 GROUP BY F2.friend_two
 ORDER BY F2.friend_two;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry if my question was not clear. I want to see my friends of friends who are not my friends so I can recommend them to a user.

Comment: As an aside, why would a username ever be null?

Comment: @Strawberry Nope. It should not never be null. Sorry.